# Vba to Access record Insert Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I want to insert Values to access table by using VBA control is there is any simple way to do this. i try this code but it does not work properly if i run this code it give the error 'variable not set' can anyone help me. thanks in advance

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim lngKt As Long
    Dim dbConnectStr As String
    Dim Catalog As Object
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbPath As String

    Dim myRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String, SQL2 As String

    dbPath = "table.accdb"
    dbConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"

   SQL = "INSERT INTO Jun_pre (ProductName,DESCRIPTION,SKU,MT,(mt),MRP,Remark,no_of_units_in_a_case) VALUES (""aa"",""bb"",""test"",""testUnit"",""1"",""2"",,""3"",,""4"");"

        With cnt
        .Open dbConnectStr 'some other string was there
        .Execute (SQL)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @HansUp: Most novice programmers are 'feeling' out solutions and I've been criminal for having a lot of 'excess' code in an 'unsolved' piece of code.  If 'we' are the experts, 'we' can sift. :D

Answer (score 5):

You are working in Access, so it is best to use DAO as it is native. Consider:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sSQL As String

sSQL = "INSERT INTO Jun_pre " _
     & "(ProductName,DESCRIPTION,SKU,MT,(mt),MRP,Remark," _
     & "no_of_units_in_a_case) VALUES "
     & "(""aa"",""bb"",""test"",""testUnit"",1,2,Null,3,Null,4);"

CurrentDB.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Against:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim lngKt As Long
    Dim dbConnectStr As String
    Dim Catalog As Object
    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbPath As String

    ''You do not need a recordset to execute an SQL statement
    ''Dim myRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String, SQL2 As String

    dbPath = "table.accdb"
    dbConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Jun_pre " _
           & "(ProductName,DESCRIPTION,SKU,MT,(mt),MRP,Remark," _
           & "no_of_units_in_a_case) VALUES "
           & "(""aa"",""bb"",""test"",""testUnit"",1,2,Null,3,Null,4);"

    With cnt
        .Open dbConnectStr 'some other string was there
        .Execute (strSQL)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

If your ADO example is inserting into the current database, it can be considerably simplified.

Note that:

- It is very unlikely that your table will
  accept a zero length string (,,), Null is
  probably better.
- I very much doubt that 2 is goining into 
  a text field, so it does not need quotes.
- SQL is a reserved word for VBA and
  should not be used to name variables.
- It is not impossible to use SQL
  injection with Access, though it can
  be difficult.
- If you give you controls
  proper names now, it will save grief
  in the future

Comment: Though you have not answered his question I am voting your answer up because your suggested way of doing things is more suited for the platform.

Comment: Ah, I remember the big hubbub of ADO for Access.  DAO is JET native and is the best approach for Access.  The language was written for Access from the onset and has matured/evolved with it.